# Neo4j query on modest Graph rather slow

Tags: neo4j

I'm toying around with Neo4J. My Data consists of users who own objects which are tagged by tags. There my schema looks like:

```
(:User)-[:OWNS]->(:Object)-[:TAGGED_AS]->(:Tag)
```

I have written a script that generates me a sample Graph. Currently I have 100 `User`, ~2500 `Tag` and ~10k `Object` nodes in the database. Between those I have ~700k relationships. I know want to find every `Object` that is not owned by a certain `User` but related over a `Tag` the `User` has used himself. There query looks like:

```
MATCH (user:User {username: 'Cristal'})
WITH user
MATCH (user)-[:OWNS]->(obj:Object)-[:TAGGED_AS]->(tag:Tag)<-[:TAGGED_AS]-(other:Object)
WHERE NOT (user)-[:OWNS]->(other)
RETURN other
LIMIT 20
```

However, this query runs ~1-5 minutes (depending on the user and how many objects he owns), which is a not only a *bit* to slow. What am I doing wrong? I consider this a rather "trivial" query against a graph of modest size. I'm using Neo4J 2.1.6 Community and already set the Java Heap to 2000 MB (and I can see that there is a Java process using this much). Am I missing an index or something like that (I'm new to Neo4J)?

I honestly expected the result to be pretty much instant especially considering that the Neo4J docs mention the I should use a heap between 1 and 4 GB for 100 million objects...and I'm only close to a 1/100 of this number.

If it is my Query (which I hope and expect) how can I improve it? What is something you have to be aware when writing queries?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an index on the username property?

```
CREATE INDEX ON :User(username)
```

Also you don't really need that `WITH` there, so maybe drop it to see if it helps:

```
MATCH (user:User {username: 'Cristal'})-[:OWNS]->(obj:Object)-[:TAGGED_AS]->(tag:Tag)<-[:TAGGED_AS]-(other:Object)
WHERE NOT (user)-[:OWNS]->(other)
RETURN other
LIMIT 20
```

Also, I don't think it will make a different, but you can drop the `obj` and `tag` variables since you're not using them elsewhere in the query.

Also, if you're generating sample graphs you may want to check out GraphGen:

http://graphgen.neoxygen.io/